# macos maven package stuck at adding directory META-INF/

Tags: java, maven

I used mvn clean package install -X and it stuck at adding directory `META-INF/`
but there is no error

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = /Users/william/IdeaProjects/modules/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) defaultManifestFile = /Users/william/IdeaProjects/modules/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[DEBUG]   (f) finalName = server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) forceCreation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/william/IdeaProjects/modules/target
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.netflix.eureka:server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/william/IdeaProjects/modules/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@a3dcc7ea
[DEBUG]   (f) skipIfEmpty = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useDefaultManifestFile = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] isUp2date: false (Destination /Users/william/IdeaProjects/modules/target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar not found.)
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/william/IdeaProjects/modules/target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
```

The project is absolutely correct. All other maven codes work, but I can't package or install they all stuck at adding directory `META-INF/`

Comment: First I would suggest to lear about the [life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) which would result into using only `clean install` instead....